# Morphia aggregation

Tags: mongodb, morphia

What I have is an aggregation pipeline from morphia with just 2 options, i.e. group and project.

2 fields to group and project the same.

Whenever I group with just one field as _id, such as below

```
.group(Group.id(Group.grouping("field1")))
```

I get the following result grouping which is correct.

```
{
    field1:"xyz"
}
{
    field1:"abcdefg"
}
```

What I want is a grouping which sums my col 'count'(int) as below and when I tried the following grouping, results are incorrect

```
.group(Group.id(Group.grouping("field1"),Group.grouping("count", Accumulator.accumulator("$sum","countfield"))))
```

Result:

```
{
    count: 10929,
    field1: "xyz"
},
{
    count: 13012,
    field1: "abcdefg"
},
{
    count: 899,
    field1: "xyz"
}
```

While what I expected was

```
{
    count: 11828,
    field1: "xyz"
},
{
    count: 13012,
    field1: "abcdefg"
}
```

I use Morphia 1.3.0 to connect to mongodb.

Comment: What object/class are you calling group() on? Can you give us a bigger code snippet. please?

Comment: @NicCottrell i think group() is invoked on 'fields' of a mongo document. So, the 'field1' above is just a column analogous to relational DBs and of course the result set and the querying document's structure are mapped to a classes as required by morphia. correct me if i'm wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the above code working, simplify by invoking static methods/ classes of morphia grouping and aggregations.

```
.group(id(grouping("field1")),grouping("count", sum("countfield")))
```